# Windows 10: Bluetooth Headphones Only "Work" When Facing Computer

Tags: windows-10, audio, bluetooth

So after a very frustrating time connecting my Sony MDR-XB950B1 headphones, I ran into something very odd. The sound only works when the receiver in the headphones is facing directly at my PC. If I shift my head slightly in any direction, the sound will cut out / fizzle out.

I have updated every possible driver I can think of. I'm assuming this has to do with a specific problem of the receiver and the Bluetooth hardware. Is it possible there's some strange interference I don't know about?

The headphones connect perfectly fine to my phone (I walked away from them in the other room), and my wireless mouse / keyboard to my PC work fine (I sit on a couch 8 feet away). I read something about USB ports and Routers affecting the signal but would it really be that noticeable

Comment: I have the same headphones, and the exact problem as you

Answer (score 0):

From my experience it could be a few things.

How close are you to your machine while wearing them? The 8ft? The machine could have a weak reciever and that could be your issue.

You could have some minor interference from the wireless mouse as that is likely BT as well. Same with the keyboard

You could have some minor interference from your Wi-Fi signal.
Are you near your kitchen? Do you notice it happening more frequently while the microwave is running?

Try to connect without some of your peripherals in use and see if that mitigates your issue some. Look and see what the effective range on your headset is.

Comment: I am like 2 feet away within the computer. I unplugged the wireless USB dongle for the keyboard/mouse. I'm Like 8 feet away from the kitchen and the microwave is almost never on. I tried unplugging everything I could but it didn't help.

Comment: It could simply just be that the Bluetooth receiver within your machine is either not that great or faulty. Because that's just about all I can figure without being there to physically troubleshoot.